# Order of printing a function

Tags: c

I need deep explanation of below program...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int dummy()  
{
    printf("dummy\n");
    return 10;
}
int main()
{
    int a=20;
    printf("%d\n%d",a,dummy());
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
dummy
20
10
```

I expected the output to be

```
20
dummy
10
```

Comment: Why would you expect that to be the output? If you move the function to a different line, does it still print the line number?

Comment: If you don’t want to return something just use void return type instead of int or nothing

Comment: The absence of a return type means it is C90 or pre-standard C — C99 and later requires an explicit return type.  Since `dummy()` is called, and returns, before the `printf()` in `main()` is called, the string `"dummy\n"` is going to appear before the number in `a`; the value printed for the result of `dummy()` is indeterminate since `dummy()` didn't explicitly return a value.  It is UB (undefined behaviour) to use the value that wasn't returned — there's no guarantee that it'll be 3.  You shouldn't be learning about pre-standard C — or, at least, you should not be writing it.

Comment: The `printf` function isn't performed piecewise. All arguments are resolved first and then passed to `printf`.

Comment: Are you sure you only got 1 number before your edit?

Comment: Changing the question should be avoided. It makes all comments and the time spent by readers worthless. That's not how helping people are attracted.

Comment: Sorry i am new to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your expected result the function would need to behave in a specific way.

The called function does not see where the values for parameters come from. It only sees it like this: `printf(fmt, par1, par2)` (I skipped details about variadic parameter list)

From this input (3 values passed) it would need to do perform the following actions:

1. Parse the format string.
2. Use first format specifier and retrieve first parameter.
3. Somehow know that second format specifier cannot be used now.
4. Using some unknown mechanism to return to the caller and find that another function must be called first.
5. Continue with second format specifier and second parameter.

Obviously this cannot happen. The function does not know anything about the parameters. It cannot return to the caller to call `dummy` and then continue printing.

What happens instead is that all parameters must be evaluated before calling `printf`. This includes calling `dummy` **before** calling `printf`.